# KeyError: 'babel' - related to __init__.py - Not using Babel explicitly

Tags: python, flask, python-babel, flask-babel

I've been getting the same error for hours, no matter what code changes I make, and it's referencing Babel, a dependency I am not specifically calling or using, although I assume it's being called for a reason. It's coming from a function that is supposed to use `flask-table` to render some HTML dynamically to make a table.

```
2018-06-08 21:30:12,121: [2018-06-08 21:30:12,114] ERROR in app: Exception on /checkin_home/ [POST]
2018-06-08 21:30:12,121: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-08 21:30:12,121:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
2018-06-08 21:30:12,121:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2018-06-08 21:30:12,121:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
2018-06-08 21:30:12,122:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2018-06-08 21:30:12,122:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
2018-06-08 21:30:12,122:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2018-06-08 21:30:12,122:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
2018-06-08 21:30:12,122:     raise value
2018-06-08 21:30:12,122:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
2018-06-08 21:30:12,122:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2018-06-08 21:30:12,122:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
2018-06-08 21:30:12,123:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2018-06-08 21:30:12,123:   File "/my/working_dir/path/mysite/project/mci.py", line 49, in checkin_home_post
2018-06-08 21:30:12,123:     return checkin_search_module.checkin_search(event_guid=event_guid, input_string=input_string)
2018-06-08 21:30:12,123:   File "/my/working_dir/path/mysite/project/checkin_search_module.py", line 3, in checkin_search
2018-06-08 21:30:12,123:     from flask_table import Table, Col
2018-06-08 21:30:12,123:   File "/my/working_dir/path/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_table/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
2018-06-08 21:30:12,123:     from .table import Table, create_table
2018-06-08 21:30:12,123:   File "/my/working_dir/path/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_table/table.py", line 8, in <module>
2018-06-08 21:30:12,124:     from .columns import Col
2018-06-08 21:30:12,124:   File "/my/working_dir/path/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_table/columns.py", line 161, in <module>
2018-06-08 21:30:12,124:     class BoolCol(OptCol):
2018-06-08 21:30:12,124:   File "/my/working_dir/path/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_table/columns.py", line 166, in BoolCol
2018-06-08 21:30:12,124:     yes_display = _('Yes')
2018-06-08 21:30:12,124:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_babel/__init__.py", line 539, in gettext
2018-06-08 21:30:12,124:     t = get_translations()
2018-06-08 21:30:12,124:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_babel/__init__.py", line 214, in get_translations
2018-06-08 21:30:12,124:     babel = current_app.extensions['babel']
2018-06-08 21:30:12,125: KeyError: 'babel'
```

On a basic level, the error seems to be: it's looking for a key `babel` in `current_app.extensions` and not finding it.

I tried reinstalling `flask-table` via `pip` (which has Babel as a dependency) and it was up do date, and I also tried reinstalling `Babel` directly, just in case, and it was also up to date. This is Python 3.6.

There are some more specific references further up to `args` and imports specific to my code, in lines 15-25 of that error, but if I run this same code in a console, it's fine, works as expected. It's just when I put it in Flask that it doesn't work. The rest of the application and routes function normally, it's only when I `POST` to `checkin_home` that I get the 500 error above.

From the research I've been able to do, it seems to have something to do with the way `__init__.py` in the given directory is being handled by the "application context" but I honestly don't really know what that means or how to fix it. All I know is it's a file in modules to tell python they're modules. I have another Flask app that renders a similar HTML table in the same environment that works fine.

I can post an approximation of the code, but it will take a ton of obfuscation of sensitive info, so before I do, I'd like to know if it's possible this is something simple I'm just not seeing.

Comment: The most recent builds for `flask_table` seem to have some problems with babel. perhaps double check your `flask_table` version is the most updated one?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had a tables.py file with

```
from flask_table import Table, Col, LinkCol
```

which worked fine when I created the app but as it grew I had to move things around. It became a large Flask app at that point and I decided to restructure everything in order to follow best practices. I followed several recommendations for structuring it with most of it coming from https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/index.html. I am therefore using the **init**.py file for creating the application factory.

To correct the error I was receiving I simply used the same import statement in the init file. It appears it is necessary to have it in both places. I'm not sure if this is the *correct* answer, but there were no other answers posted and this worked for me. If anyone with more experience feels otherwise, please politely correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing flask-babel and doing the following in your app initialization

```
from flask_babel import Babel

babel = Babel(app)
```

and retry.